# Erro ao usar o RadTreeList da Telerik

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms, telerik

Estou tentando utilizar o [RadTreeList](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) em uma aplicação WebForms com MasterPage sem sucesso pois ocorre erro nas tags html:

```
Linha 59:     <qsf:ConfiguratorPanel runat="server" ID="ConfiguratorPanel1"
```

Já tentei trocar de: `<qsf:ConfiguratorPanel` para `<asp:ConfiguratorPanel` mas `ConfiguratorPanel` não é um controle do AspNet.

No code já referenciei o `using Telerik.Web.UI;`

**Esta é a página Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTreelist._Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>
    <%@ Register TagPrefix="qsf" Namespace="Telerik.QuickStart" %>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
        <telerik:RadSkinManager ID="RadSkinManager1" runat="server" ShowChooser="true" />
        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server" DefaultLoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
            <ajaxsettings>
          <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadTreeList1">
            <UpdatedControls>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTreeList1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
          </telerik:AjaxSetting>
          <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ConfiguratorPanel1">
            <UpdatedControls>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadTreeList1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
              <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="ConfiguratorPanel1"></telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl>
            </UpdatedControls>
          </telerik:AjaxSetting>
        </ajaxsettings>
        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
        <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server">
        </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
        <telerik:RadTreeList RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadTreeList1" runat="server" OnNeedDataSource="RadTreeList1_NeedDataSource" ParentDataKeyNames="ParentID" DataKeyNames="ID" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" ExpandCollapseMode="Client">
            <clientsettings>
          <Selecting AllowItemSelection="true" />
        </clientsettings>
            <columns>
          <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="ID" UniqueName="ID" HeaderText="Category ID">
          </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
          <telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn DataField="ProductName" UniqueName="ProductName" HeaderText="Product">
            <ItemTemplate>
              <%# Eval("ProductName")%>
                <%# Eval("Quantity").ToString() != "" ? "&nbsp;(" + Eval("Quantity").ToString() + ")" : ""%>
            </ItemTemplate>
          </telerik:TreeListTemplateColumn>
          <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="Price" UniqueName="Price" DataFormatString="{0:C2}" HeaderText="Price" DataType="System.Decimal">
          </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
          <telerik:TreeListCheckBoxColumn DataField="InStock" UniqueName="InStock" HeaderText="In stock">
          </telerik:TreeListCheckBoxColumn>
          <telerik:TreeListBoundColumn DataField="ParentID" UniqueName="ParentID" HeaderText="Parent Category ID">
          </telerik:TreeListBoundColumn>
        </columns>
        </telerik:RadTreeList>
        <qsf:ConfiguratorPanel runat="server" ID="ConfiguratorPanel1" Title="Demo Configurator">
            <views>
          <qsf:View>
            <qsf:ConfiguratorColumn ID="ConfiguratorColumn1" runat="server" Size="Narrow">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Visual Options</legend>
              </fieldset>
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Text="Show outer borders" Checked="true"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox>
                        </span>
              <br />
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" Text="Show tree lines" Checked="true"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox2_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox></span><br />
              <br />
              <label for="DropDownList1">
                            Change treelist lines:</label>
              <qsf:ComboBox runat="server" Size="Medium" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" ID="ComboBox1" AutoPostBack="true">
                <Items>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Selected="True" Text="Both" Value="Both" />
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Horizontal" Value="Horizontal"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="None" Value="None"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Vertical" Value="Vertical"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                </Items>
              </qsf:ComboBox>
            </qsf:ConfiguratorColumn>
            <qsf:ConfiguratorColumn ID="ConfiguratorColumn2" runat="server" Size="Narrow">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>TreeList Options</legend>
              </fieldset>
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" Text="Enable paging" Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true"
                                OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox3_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox></span><br />
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox4" runat="server" Text="Enable sorting" Checked="true"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox4_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox></span>
              <br />
              <br />
              <label for="RadComboBox1">
                            Expand Collapse Mode:</label>
              <qsf:ComboBox ID="ComboBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" Size="Medium" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <Items>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Client" Value="Client" Selected="True"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Server" Value="Server"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                  <telerik:RadComboBoxItem Text="Combined" Value="Combined"></telerik:RadComboBoxItem>
                </Items>
              </qsf:ComboBox>
            </qsf:ConfiguratorColumn>
            <qsf:ConfiguratorColumn ID="ConfiguratorColumn3" runat="server" Size="Wide">
              <fieldset>
                <legend>Selection Options</legend>
              </fieldset>
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox5" runat="server" Text="Enable client-side items selection"
                                Checked="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox5_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox></span><br />
              <span class="checkbox">
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox6" runat="server" Text="Allow multi-item selection" Checked="false"
                                AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox6_CheckedChanged"></asp:CheckBox></span>
            </qsf:ConfiguratorColumn>
          </qsf:View>
        </views>
        </qsf:ConfiguratorPanel>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**Esta é a master page**

```
<%@  Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="WebTreelist.SiteMaster" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="telerik" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head runat="server">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="styles/offcanvas.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server" />

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container body-content">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <form id="form1" runat="server">

                <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager1" />
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="scripts/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js/colapsemenu.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que é necessário para o AspNet reconheça esses elementos do html do Telerik ?

Comment: QuickStart não é o name space do componente e sim do projeto de exemplo de implementação... Você precisa adicionar a referência para essa dll a indicar o assembly no register

Comment: Não tenho a referencia para essa `dll` eu copiei o `html` do site [Teleriki RadTreeList](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx), tenho sim comigo a `Telerik.Web.UI.dll`  que é usado atualmente em algumas páginas do sistema legado aqui da empresa para utilizar objeto `RadComboBox` e estou estudando usar esse componente `RadTreeList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o register do `Telerik.QuickStart`, assim como todos os componentes desse prefixo. Segundo a própria Telerik eles só são utilizados para a configuração e exibição nas páginas de live demos deles.

[Fonte](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Common/QSFInstructions/Instructions.html)

Comment: Funcionou @Leandro Angelo obrigado agora sim entendi.